# input operation

Tags: c++

Consider this problem
User will enter input to one dimensional array`(char test[100])` in sequence of
letter/space/index/space/letter....
like this
**a 1 s 1 e 3 r 4 r 3 t 3**  until an `'enter'`is hit.
Index can be repeated as well as letter.
So above sequence should mean `test[1]=a ,test[1]=s` and so on.
To build this problem what I have thought is that ***I should test whether character entered is newline(enter) or not.***
but i don't understand how to do that

can you suggest some code for this

Comment: Hint : Use std::string, std::getline and tokenize based on space character.

Comment: To answer your question about the newline character, it is a regular character, in the sense of being represented as a number from 0 to 255 that fits in a `char` type. Since you cannot "enter" it directly between single quotes the way you do with other characters, you need to follow a convention: `'\n'` means "newline character".

Answer (score 1):

Scrap the entire idea; your question is wrong. The user does **not** enter a `char[100]`. Rather, the user enters a **string**. And suddenly it's very easy:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string user_input;

    std::getline(std::cin, user_input);

    // done: now use user_input
}
```

Now you can iterate over the string, tokenize it, or whatever. For example:

```
std::istringstream iss(user_input);
char c;
int n;

while (iss >> c >> n)
{
    std::cout << "We have a pair (" << c << ", " << n << ")\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 Amazing. We are at different parts of the world unified by thoughts called `C++`.

Comment: he didn't say the user enters a char[100].

Comment: i am getting error in your code at line std::istringstream iss(user_input).Error is variable iss has initializer but not complete type

Comment: @T.J.: You also need to `#include <sstream>`.